# How do I change the raised power of an exponent in Python?

Tags: python, exponential

I am trying to fetch a value from a webpage that is in scientific notation `3.67E+17` and then convert it to a form `0.367E+18`. Or if the scientific notation is `0.367E+18`, then fetch exactly that value. I have been able to implement the part where I open up the webpage and then find where that scientific number is, however, I haven't been able to convert the number itself to the form that I want.

I got this far though:

```
lsF = "3.18E+20"
int(lsF[lsF.find("E")+2:]) - 18
```

I have been able to figure out how many decimal places I need to shift, either left or right, however, how do I actually shift them?

Comment: Add 1 to the exponent and divide the mantissa by 10.

Comment: Why are you adding `2` to the position of `E`? You should just add `1`, since you need the `+` or `-` to know if it's a positive or negative exponent.

Comment: @JohnColeman Does `format()` allow you to control how many digits before the decimal point when using exponential notation?

Comment: @JohnColeman How would you directly access the exponent from the float?

Comment: That's the binary mantissa and exponent, he wants the decimal ones.

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't wanna display it, but actually use the value in further calculations

Comment: @AkshatTripathi If you don't want to display it, why do you care what the format is? Just convert it to a float and use it like that.

Comment: Okay, so, I will feed the value into another software which expects the value to be in the power of 18. And I cannot change the value of the number by multiplying it or dividing it by 10

Comment: I've never heard of software like that. These powers are only used for input and output to humans, internally computers represent numbers in binary floating point.. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: So if the original number were `3.1E10` you would need `0.000000031E18`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I will need

Comment: Barmar's answer is nice and simple.  If you're looking for library support, there is [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) and specifically `Decimal.as_tuple` to decompose the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsF = "3.18E+20"
ePos = lsF.find("E")
if (ePos):
    mantissa = float(lsF[:ePos])
    exponent = int(lsF[ePos+1:])
else:
    mantissa = float(lsF)
    exponent = 0
shift = 18 - exponent
result = mantissa / 10**shift
```

`result` will be the new mantissa for exponent `18`